# I encountered a problem when installing Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js, npx

I was installing NextJS when I encountered the following error:

```
D:\Codes\React\Learn>npx create-next-app
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 File Not Found - GET https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/create-next-app
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'create-next-app@latest' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-06T12_41_40_938Z-debug-0.log
```

Can anyone help me?

I wanted to work with NextJS......but I encountered this error!

Comment: have you tried with `npx create-next-app@latest` ?

Comment: yes .I tried it

Answer (score 0):

You should give directory address in the installation command ,

Try : `npx create-next-app@latest .` if you want to install the packages in current directory or

`npx create-next-app@latest YOUR_FOLDER_NAME` and packages will be installed in new folder with the given name as YOUR_FOLDER_NAME.

Comment: I don't think the 404 error has anything to do with the location of the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm i -g create-next-app
```

It will install create next app globally. To create a next app run this command, if you want to install in current folder.

```
npx create-next-app
```

Otherwise, specify the folder name like,

```
npx create-next-app [your app name]
```

Comment: I tried the ways you said.....but I still got error 404!

Comment: Clear the npm cache by running           ``` npm cache clean --force```         and try installing again. If it not works then..
Try updating npm to the latest version by running ```npm install npm@latest -g```

Comment: When I use the npm or npx command to download a package, I get an error.
Thank you very much for your help, but I get a 404 error when updating npm.

Comment: Have you tried to install npm from os terminal not from code editor.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? thank you

Comment: If you are executing the commands to update or install packages from the code editor's terminal then close that and open the terminal of your operating system then try install or update npm globally. See if it's still giving error.

Comment: Yes, it still gives an error!

Comment: No npm command working for you? Then try uninstall it and reinstall.

Comment: Before that try this command `npx  create-next-js-app my-app`

Comment: How do I delete it?

Comment: Go to windows control panel and search for node js app uninstall the app. Then turn off your pc and reinstall it.  If you are in linux run this command `sudo apt-get remove nodejs`
`sudo apt-get remove npm`

Comment: It didn't work again. I sincerely thank you for your guidance.
I think I should refer this problem to the npm developers.

Comment: Do you think there is another way?

Comment: Where you creating the app? Try to change the directory.

Comment: Or just install it manually

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started

Answer (score -1):

Please uninstall node.js and install its latest lts version from https://nodejs.org/en/download , then try to do npx create-next-app@latest  as stated in https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/installation. I think it should work